# How to prevent string.Replace() method from replacing similar but unwanted data?

Tags: c#, winforms, replace

The string.Replace() method is replacing chars that should not be replaced. I am trying to replace dates like this: 1/1/2019, 2/2/2019, 3/3/2019

With dates like this: 01/01/2019, 02/02/2019, 03/03/2019

The problem is that my code only provides me with:

1/01/2019 (if I use "/1/") or 02/02/02019 depending on which code I use.

```
    //public readonly string[] dateStringErrors = { "/1/", "/2/", "/3/", "/4/", "/5/", "/6/", "/7/", "/8/", "/9/" }; // uncomment if below code fails
    public readonly string[] dateStringErrors = { "1/", "2/", "3/", "4/", "5/", "6/", "7/", "8/", "9/" };

    //public readonly string[] fixedDateStrings = { "/01/", "/02/", "/03/", "/04/", "/05/", "/06/", "/07/", "/08/", "/09/" }; // uncomment if below code fails
    public readonly string[] fixedDateStrings = { "01/", "02/", "03/", "04/", "05/", "06/", "07/", "08/", "09/" };

    public string FixDateStrings(string input)
    {
        //  Invalid Date Strings, 9 indexes in array
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // i represents index for dateStrings
        {
            input = input.Replace(dateStringErrors[i], fixedDateStrings[i]);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

---

Results from the commented out version:
(Partially works)

10/18/2019 - $65.91

11/01/2019 - $65.91

11/15/2019 - $65.90

---

Results from the above code:
(Completely breaks)

10/19/2019 - $65.91

101/02/2019 - $65.91

101/106/2019 - $65.90

The problem is obvious. I'm looking to get the dates to all line up evenly.

---

EDIT:
I switched to a monofont (Courier New) and then using excel I created all of the dates I needed.

My code is spaghetti and its a 2 forms with ~4,000 lines of code and no class/class libraries. I am a new C# developer and this is my first practical project. I need to learn class libraries but for the time being I was looking for a 'patch job'

This is what I eventually came up with (The dates were merged, copied, formatted, pasted and it was a mess so I had to do it like this):

```
    public readonly string[] dateStringErrors = 
        { "1/1/", "1/2/", "1/3/", "1/4/", "1/5/", "1/6/", "1/7/", "1/8/", "1/9/", "1/10/", "1/11/", "1/12/",
        "1/13/", "1/14/", "1/15/", "1/16/", "1/17/", "1/18/", "1/19/", "1/20/", "1/21/", "1/22/", "1/23/", "1/24/", "1/25/", "1/26/", "1/27/", "1/28/",
        "1/29/", "1/30/", "1/31/", "2/1/", "2/2/", "2/3/", "2/4/", "2/5/", "2/6/", "2/7/", "2/8/", "2/9/", "2/10/", "2/11/", "2/12/", "2/13/", "2/14/",
        "2/15/", "2/16/", "2/17/", "2/18/", "2/19/", "2/20/", "2/21/", "2/22/", "2/23/", "2/24/", "2/25/", "2/26/", "2/27/", "2/28/", "2/29/", "3/1/",
        "3/2/", "3/3/", "3/4/", "3/5/", "3/6/", "3/7/", "3/8/", "3/9/", "3/10/", "3/11/", "3/12/", "3/13/", "3/14/", "3/15/", "3/16/", "3/17/", "3/18/",
        "3/19/", "3/20/", "3/21/", "3/22/", "3/23/", "3/24/", "3/25/", "3/26/", "3/27/", "3/28/", "3/29/", "3/30/", "3/31/", "4/1/", "4/2/", "4/3/",
        "4/4/", "4/5/", "4/6/", "4/7/", "4/8/", "4/9/", "4/10/", "4/11/", "4/12/", "4/13/", "4/14/", "4/15/", "4/16/", "4/17/", "4/18/", "4/19/",
        "4/20/", "4/21/", "4/22/", "4/23/", "4/24/", "4/25/", "4/26/", "4/27/", "4/28/", "4/29/", "4/30/", "5/1/", "5/2/", "5/3/", "5/4/", "5/5/",
        "5/6/", "5/7/", "5/8/", "5/9/", "5/10/", "5/11/", "5/12/", "5/13/", "5/14/", "5/15/", "5/16/", "5/17/", "5/18/", "5/19/", "5/20/", "5/21/",
        "5/22/", "5/23/", "5/24/", "5/25/", "5/26/", "5/27/", "5/28/", "5/29/", "5/30/", "5/31/", "6/1/", "6/2/", "6/3/", "6/4/", "6/5/", "6/6/",
        "6/7/", "6/8/", "6/9/", "6/10/", "6/11/", "6/12/", "6/13/", "6/14/", "6/15/", "6/16/", "6/17/", "6/18/", "6/19/", "6/20/", "6/21/", "6/22/",
        "6/23/", "6/24/", "6/25/", "6/26/", "6/27/", "6/28/", "6/29/", "6/30/", "7/1/", "7/2/", "7/3/", "7/4/", "7/5/", "7/6/", "7/7/", "7/8/", "7/9/",
        "7/10/", "7/11/", "7/12/", "7/13/", "7/14/", "7/15/", "7/16/", "7/17/", "7/18/", "7/19/", "7/20/", "7/21/", "7/22/", "7/23/", "7/24/", "7/25/",
        "7/26/", "7/27/", "7/28/", "7/29/", "7/30/", "7/31/", "8/1/", "8/2/", "8/3/", "8/4/", "8/5/", "8/6/", "8/7/", "8/8/", "8/9/", "8/10/", "8/11/",
        "8/12/", "8/13/", "8/14/", "8/15/", "8/16/", "8/17/", "8/18/", "8/19/", "8/20/", "8/21/", "8/22/", "8/23/", "8/24/", "8/25/", "8/26/", "8/27/",
        "8/28/", "8/29/", "8/30/", "8/31/", "9/1/", "9/2/", "9/3/", "9/4/", "9/5/", "9/6/", "9/7/", "9/8/", "9/9/", "9/10/", "9/11/", "9/12/", "9/13/",
        "9/14/", "9/15/", "9/16/", "9/17/", "9/18/", "9/19/", "9/20/", "9/21/", "9/22/", "9/23/", "9/24/", "9/25/", "9/26/", "9/27/", "9/28/", "9/29/",
        "9/30/", "10/1/", "10/2/", "10/3/", "10/4/", "10/5/", "10/6/", "10/7/", "10/8/", "10/9/", "11/1/", "11/2/", "11/3/", "11/4/", "11/5/", "11/6/",
        "11/7/", "11/8/", "11/9/", "12/1/", "12/2/", "12/3/", "12/4/", "12/5/", "12/6/", "12/7/", "12/8/", "12/9/" };

    public readonly string[] fixedDateStrings = 
        { "01/01/", "01/02/", "01/03/", "01/04/", "01/05/", "01/06/", "01/07/", "01/08/", "01/09/", "01/10/",
        "01/11/", "01/12/", "01/13/", "01/14/", "01/15/", "01/16/", "01/17/", "01/18/", "01/19/", "01/20/", "01/21/", "01/22/", "01/23/", "01/24/",
        "01/25/", "01/26/", "01/27/", "01/28/", "01/29/", "01/30/", "01/31/", "02/01/", "02/02/", "02/03/", "02/04/", "02/05/", "02/06/", "02/07/",
        "02/08/", "02/09/", "02/10/", "02/11/", "02/12/", "02/13/", "02/14/", "02/15/", "02/16/", "02/17/", "02/18/", "02/19/", "02/20/", "02/21/",
        "02/22/", "02/23/", "02/24/", "02/25/", "02/26/", "02/27/", "02/28/", "02/29/", "03/01/", "03/02/", "03/03/", "03/04/", "03/05/", "03/06/",
        "03/07/", "03/08/", "03/09/", "03/10/", "03/11/", "03/12/", "03/13/", "03/14/", "03/15/", "03/16/", "03/17/", "03/18/", "03/19/", "03/20/",
        "03/21/", "03/22/", "03/23/", "03/24/", "03/25/", "03/26/", "03/27/", "03/28/", "03/29/", "03/30/", "03/31/", "04/01/", "04/02/", "04/03/",
        "04/04/", "04/05/", "04/06/", "04/07/", "04/08/", "04/09/", "04/10/", "04/11/", "04/12/", "04/13/", "04/14/", "04/15/", "04/16/", "04/17/",
        "04/18/", "04/19/", "04/20/", "04/21/", "04/22/", "04/23/", "04/24/", "04/25/", "04/26/", "04/27/", "04/28/", "04/29/", "04/30/", "05/01/",
        "05/02/", "05/03/", "05/04/", "05/05/", "05/06/", "05/07/", "05/08/", "05/09/", "05/10/", "05/11/", "05/12/", "05/13/", "05/14/", "05/15/",
        "05/16/", "05/17/", "05/18/", "05/19/", "05/20/", "05/21/", "05/22/", "05/23/", "05/24/", "05/25/", "05/26/", "05/27/", "05/28/", "05/29/",
        "05/30/", "05/31/", "06/01/", "06/02/", "06/03/", "06/04/", "06/05/", "06/06/", "06/07/", "06/08/", "06/09/", "06/10/", "06/11/", "06/12/",
        "06/13/", "06/14/", "06/15/", "06/16/", "06/17/", "06/18/", "06/19/", "06/20/", "06/21/", "06/22/", "06/23/", "06/24/", "06/25/", "06/26/",
        "06/27/", "06/28/", "06/29/", "06/30/", "07/01/", "07/02/", "07/03/", "07/04/", "07/05/", "07/06/", "07/07/", "07/08/", "07/09/", "07/10/",
        "07/11/", "07/12/", "07/13/", "07/14/", "07/15/", "07/16/", "07/17/", "07/18/", "07/19/", "07/20/", "07/21/", "07/22/", "07/23/", "07/24/",
        "07/25/", "07/26/", "07/27/", "07/28/", "07/29/", "07/30/", "07/31/", "08/01/", "08/02/", "08/03/", "08/04/", "08/05/", "08/06/", "08/07/",
        "08/08/", "08/09/", "08/10/", "08/11/", "08/12/", "08/13/", "08/14/", "08/15/", "08/16/", "08/17/", "08/18/", "08/19/", "08/20/", "08/21/",
        "08/22/", "08/23/", "08/24/", "08/25/", "08/26/", "08/27/", "08/28/", "08/29/", "08/30/", "08/31/", "09/01/", "09/02/", "09/03/", "09/04/",
        "09/05/", "09/06/", "09/07/", "09/08/", "09/09/", "09/10/", "09/11/", "09/12/", "09/13/", "09/14/", "09/15/", "09/16/", "09/17/", "09/18/",
        "09/19/", "09/20/", "09/21/", "09/22/", "09/23/", "09/24/", "09/25/", "09/26/", "09/27/", "09/28/", "09/29/", "09/30/", "10/01/", "10/02/",
        "10/03/", "10/04/", "10/05/", "10/06/", "10/07/", "10/08/", "10/09/", "11/01/", "11/02/", "11/03/", "11/04/", "11/05/", "11/06/", "11/07/",
        "11/08/", "11/09/", "12/01/", "12/02/", "12/03/", "12/04/", "12/05/", "12/06/", "12/07/", "12/08/", "12/09/" };

{
        //  Re-Format Date Strings, 300 indexes in array
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) // i represents index for dateStrings
        {
            input = input.Replace(dateStringErrors[i], fixedDateStrings[i]);
            input = input.Replace("101", "11"); // Fix November Date Formatting (also in a very inefficient way)
            input = input.Replace("102", "12"); // Fix December Date Formatting (also in a very inefficient way)
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Not ideal but it works. Maybe it can help someone else someday.

Comment: Those are dates. Break the string apart, parse the dates as `DateTime`, and choose an appropriate output format string.

Comment: _"Is this something that needs REGEX as a solution?"_ -- not necessarily, no. You can do it without regex. But you'll certainly need something at least a little more sophisticated than strictly search-and-replace. Have you tried?

Comment: Fabio's answer is very clean and I recommend it. If you were to roll your own, however, you would want to tokenize your input.

Comment: For a quick-and-dirty solution, you can also put a "/" before each of your strings before replacing. Then again, for anything quick-and-dirty, I suggest you try Python (or any other language with an interactive console).

Comment: If the data you are working with was something like `"6/23/2019 - $100.00"` then another XY aspect is not to store 2 bits of data in one var or string.

Comment: I hope nobody will use this approach, especially in projects where more than one developer involved. Because it would be difficult to read and to maintain.

Comment: If this wasn't the final feature in my first ever winforms app which was solely a learning exercise for me, and if I started over again knowing what I know now, I would have taken care of this when I exported the datetime data from the datagridview. The data has been manipulated half a dozen times and the code is a disaster.

Comment: 90% of developer's work is maintaining already existing applications. You can have another good lesson and fix existing application.

Answer (score 9):

If you work with dates - use right tool/type for the job - `DateTime`

In your particular case when you have dates as a strings, you can convert it to the `DateTime` and then format to the string format you need.

```
var givenDate = "1/31/2019";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    givenDate, 
    @"M/d/yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var output = date.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy"); // 01/31/2019
```

Comment: "If you works with dates - use right tool/type for the job - DateTime" +1! It's depressing how often people write reams of crap code and ignore the standard libraries of their languages and runtimes.

Comment: I know, +1. I agree but this is my first ever app. I'm 3 months and thousands of lines into this. The code is spaghetti and the dates have been copied, moved, formatted as strings and merged.

Comment: @RobertBass, even with spaghetti code you can use correct approach, which will help you in the future.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have a theory. In programming courses, too often an instructor says this in an assignment: "Don't use this library function --- write your own code". It is no wonder that some people emerge from those courses thinking library functions are bad.

Comment: @ImperishableNight you're absolutely right. I experienced that exact phenomenon during my formal education. In their defense, teachers often want students to learn some fundamentals by coding their own versions of basic data structures, but they don't explain why you almost never want to actually do that beyond your 1st year of education.